# Unable to fetch text from textbox using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

Hi I am new to the tkinter module, I am trying to get the text entered into the textbox, so that the editimage() will write that text on the specified image.

Here is the Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import messagebox as mb


def callback():
    name = fd.askopenfilename()
    global filename
    global input_text
    filename = name.replace('/', '\\')
    if filename:
        Window.geometry('500x250')
        tkinter.Label(Window,
                      text='File has been selected, now click on edit image'
                      ).pack(fill=tkinter.X, padx=5, pady=5)
        tkinter.Label(Window, text='Enter text').pack(fill=tkinter.X,
                padx=5, pady=5)

        # I am unable to get the text using this. Need to pass it to the editimage() to write this text on an image.

        inputtxt = tkinter.Text(Window, height=3, width=25)
        inputtxt.pack()
        input_text = inputtxt.get('1.0', 'end-1c')

        tkinter.Button(Window, text='Edit Image',
                       command=editimage).pack(fill=None, padx=15,
                pady=15)


def editimage():
    try:
        image = Image.open(filename)

        # initialise the drawing context with
        # the image object as background

        (width, height) = image.size
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
        xy = [0, height - 50, 942, 586]
        draw.rectangle(xy, fill='white', outline=None)

        # create font object with the font file and specify
        # desired size

        font = ImageFont.truetype('C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Times.ttf',
                                  size=22)

        # starting position of the message

        (x, y) = (width / 2 - width * 0.3, height - 40)
        message = input_text
        colour = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'  # black color

        # draw the message on the background

        draw.text((x, y), message, fill=colour, font=font)

        # save the edited image

        image.save('Edited.png')
        mb.showinfo('Photo-Editor',
                    'The Photo has been edited succesfully')
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Failed to edit the image'
        print str(e)


Window = tkinter.Tk()
Window.geometry('500x90')
Window.title('Photo-Editor')
errmsg = 'Error!'
tkinter.Label(Window,
              text='Click on Browse for selecting the image file'
              ).pack(fill=tkinter.X, padx=5, pady=5)

tkinter.Button(Window, text='Browse', command=callback).pack(fill=None,
        padx=5, pady=5)
Window.mainloop()
```

I tried printing it as well, but I am getting an empty string. ANy help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You call `input_text = inputtxt.get(...)` just after `inputtxt = tkinter.Text(...)`. You need to give some time to the user to enter the data in the text box. You should move the `input_text = inputtxt.get(...)` inside `editimage`

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I moved it to the editimage(). After doing this it is working fine. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: I have another question. How can we reset the window again? What I mean is what if I want to select another image and edit that. When I do that now, I am seeing another textbox getting added to the tkinter window. Typing it in the second one will make sure it works, but this is a problem if I have to do this for multiple images. I understand that this is because of the condition I have in place to show the textbox is by clicking on browse and selecting an image. Is there any way I can make sure only one textbox is shown always?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be too hard actually, and your code looks fine to me, I don't understand why it isn't working. Refer to the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

def command():
  input1 = textarea.get("1.0", "end-1c")
  print(input1)

root = Tk()

textarea = Text(root)
textarea.pack()

btn = Button(root, text="Click here", command=command)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

That code works for me. Hopefully for you too. Let me know if not. Thanks, and happy coding!